# Show that [x] is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image: It is about cardinality of infinite sets.]

The problem 1 is that: I am not sure about the relation symbol (corner of the $[x]$) means.

Problem 2: I think that if $ x-y \in \mathbb{Q} $, then $x$ and $y$ must be in $\mathbb{Q}$. So all $y$s that make $ x-y \in \mathbb{Q} $ are in $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus they form a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is denumerable, $[x]$ is denumerable.

Hope I am clear, thank you !

Comment: It is not true that $x-y\in \mathbb Q\implies x,y\in \mathbb Q$.  Consider $\pi-\pi$ for example.

Comment: Problem 1: The notation $[x]_\sim$ denotes the $\sim$-equivalance class of $x$.

Comment: Oh, so the usual equivalance classes.

It is not true for general, it is a condition for relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use $[x]$ for the equivalence class of $x.$ A real number $y$ belongs to $[x]$ if and only if $x-y$ is a rational number. This happens if and only if $y=x+q$ for some rational number $q.$ Hence, the number of elements in the equivalence class of $x$ is the same as the number of rationals, that is, $[x]$ is denumerable (by which I'm assuming you mean countably infinite).

For your third question, consider that all rationals belong to the same equivalence class. Next, let $x$ and $y$ be distinct irrationals for which $x-y$ is not rational. What can you say about $[x]$ and $[y]?$ Does that suggest a strategy?

Comment: Depending on how comfortable you are with cardinalities, you can give an answer to the third question by noting that $\mathbb{R}$ is the disjoint union of the distinct equivalence classes of the relation. But $\mathbb{R}$ in uncountable and all equivalence classes are denumerable, so the number of equivalence classes must be ... .